# Laravel - How to pass a php variable to a javascript function from a blade file

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an html element inside my blade file:

```
<input id="check_all" onclick="toggleCheckOrders('$orderFormObject', ' $count')" name="check_all" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

The onclick handler is assigned a javascript function toggleCheckOrders which accepts two parameters which are objects that were passed from the controller to the blade template. When I do this, it just treats them as strings inside the javascript function, it there a way to pass them while retaining their respective data types?

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
<input id="check_all" onclick="toggleCheckOrders('{{ $orderFormObject }}', ' {{ $count }}')" name="check_all" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

In Blade you use `{{ ... }}` to echo variable value

Comment: I just tried that but it throws an error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: @VinceGonzales `json_encode` and then parse on JS side. Laravel's `{{ }}` not only echos but it also escapes via `htmlspecialchars` as the error suggests.

Comment: So it seems, you pass here something else, do you really want to pass the whole PHP object? If yes, you can use `json_encode`

Comment: So it's gonna be: toggleCheckOrders('{{ json_encode($orderFormObject) }}', '{{ $count }}')" . Right?

Comment: @VinceGonzales remove the single quotes arround the {{ }}. `json_encode` will add quotes to the variable if necessary.

Comment: I tried json_encode, but when I receive it in the javascript function, the array is empty

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little helper I wrote for myself:

I added this in my `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
 Blade::directive('jsvar', function ($expression) {
     return "<?php echo json_encode($expression); ?>";
 });
```

This will allow you to do:

```
<input id="check_all" onclick="toggleCheckOrders(@jsvar($orderFormObject), @jsvar($count))" name="check_all" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

If you find yourself passing PHP variables to JavaScript often I highly recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do

```
<input id="check_all" onclick="toggleCheckOrders({{json_encode($orderFormObject)}}, {{ json_encode($count)}})" name="check_all" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

carefull that associative array will be casted as object in JavaScript

Comment: How do I parse $orderFormObject in the javascript function tho? It's actually a form object passed from the controller

Comment: well, dump it and check what you need from it. it might not contain what you need anyway.

Comment: Yeah I did, but it was an empty object, so I thought there was something else that needed to be done

Comment: what are you looking for in the first parameter ?

Comment: The first parameter is actually a form object from the controller, I'm trying to pass the form object to get the elements of the form.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML do as seen below:

```
<input id="check_all" onclick="jsFunction(`{{json_encode($orderFormObject)}}`, `{{ json_encode($count)}}`)" name="check_all" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

In javascript, do the following:

```
<script>
  function jsFunction(orderFormObject, count) {
      const orderFormObjectNew = JSON.parse(orderFormObject);

      console.log(orderFormObjectNew);
      console.log(count);
  }
</script>
```

I hope this will be helpful.